How can I make an enemy stay away from the player, but can still see it
I am making a game in Unreal Engine and I wanted to know how can I make an enemy always attack from a certain distance, however, the enemy also has to see the player.
I've reached a weird result where it picks a random position on a thorus but I don't like it, for example, it walks near the player, I don't want that.
For comparison see the Stray from Ultrakill

If you're "shooting a ray" at an enemy, and you hit something in between (and it's a hill, for example), you can assume the enemy can't be seen (if it's a big enough hill). So, find all "in range" and then test if you can "see" them. Then you have to decide from all the candidates: nearest; strongest; weakest ... i.e. which to attack from all "in range".

I was overcomplicating, I ended up just making a ray from the player that passes trough the enemy with a certain length and move the enemy to the collision point or where it ends.

You create a state machine, and when the enemy is in a state of aggression, check the ray from the enemy to the player, if he does not collide with the player, you switch the state, for example, direct the enemy to the player's current(or last) coordinates

but then it would not be at a certain distance from the player, that is, if the player is near, run away
